# Mysql procedure drop table, error code 1054

Tags: mysql

I have a issue when I try to create a procedure.

First with :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS curr_rate;
```

There no problem the table is dropped.

Now with a procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Drop_table_Gen`(IN tname varchar(20))
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `',tname,'`');

    PREPARE stm FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stm;
END
```

I get the following error:

> error code 1054 Unknown column

The same issue if I write :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `drop_table_gen2`(IN tname varchar(20))
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tname;

END
```

I hope someone has an idea about this problem

Thanks

Comment: How you are calling procedure `Drop_table_Gen`? I mean what parameter you are passing? I doubt you are passing empty string.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I call the procedure like that : call Drop_table_Gen(curr_rate);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are calling like `call Drop_table_Gen(curr_rate);`. shouldn't you be quoting the parameter like `call Drop_table_Gen('curr_rate');` since it's a `VARCHAR` type.

If still same error then I don't see anything wrong with the way you are trying to drop the table. To my believe, somehow `IF EXIST` is creating the problem here. Try without that (below procedure) and it will work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Drop_table_Gen`(IN tname varchar(20))
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT('DROP TABLE `',tname,'`');

    PREPARE stm FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stm;
END
```

If you are using MySQL 5.5 or above then you can use `EXIT HANDLER` for error catching within your procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Drop_table_Gen`(IN tname varchar(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    SET @error_count = @error_count + 1;
    IF @a = 0 THEN RESIGNAL; END IF;
END;
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT('DROP TABLE `',tname,'`');

    PREPARE stm FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stm;
END
```

Then while calling the procedure

```
SET @error_count = 0;
SET @a = 0;
CALL Drop_table_Gen('curr_rate');
```

So in case, table doesn't exist it will pop up the SQL error

> ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'curr_rate'

See a detailed document here [RESIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html)

Comment: Thanks Rahul, the problem was the quoting .